# Detecting where a newline is located in a string:

Tags: c#, string

I see using the Visual Studio object viewer that my string is:

```
"_profileIconId = 5\n            elo"
```

What I need to get the text from beginning to where the newline is.

Here's what I've tried, but the IndexOf() method returns -1, meaning a newline isn't found.

```
var stringEx = "_profileIconId = 5\n            elo";
var x = stringEx.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
stat.Name = tempName.Substring(0,x);
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sergio I was getting to the CR+LF \r\n Windows linebreak vs. *nix single character line breaks, but you've got some answers now!

Answer (score 19):

That's because `Environment.NewLine` represents `\r\n` (a carriage return + line feed) whereas you only have a line feed in your source string. Change the second line to this:

```
var x = stringEx.IndexOf("\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the first line of the string, you could do this:

```
static string GetFirstLine(string text)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(text))
    {
        return reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The `StringReader` class deals with various line-break scenarios for you. From [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline.aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of
>   characters followed by a line feed
>   ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a
>   carriage return immediately followed
>   by a line feed ("\r\n").

Of course, if you don't want the overhead of constructing a new `StringReader` object (though I doubt it's that big), you could implement something similar yourself:

```
static string GetFirstLine(string text)
{
    int? newlinePos = GetIndex(text, "\r") ?? GetIndex(text, "\n");

    if (newlinePos.HasValue)
    {
        return text.Substring(0, newlinePos.Value);
    }

    return text;
}

// Not really necessary -- just a convenience method.
static int? GetIndex(string text, string substr)
{
    int index = text.IndexOf(substr);
    return index >= 0 ? (int?)index : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on a Windows platform, [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) will look for "\r\n".

Try looking for \n instead:

```
var x = stringEx.IndexOf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general way to do this that will *remove* a new line and everything after it from the string, but only when a new line exists in the string:

```
int x = stringEx.IndexOf("\n");

if (x > 0) {
  stringEx= stringEx.Remove(x);
}
```